# How can I disable clear of Clipboard on exit of WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, clipboard

If I copy a text of my application to clipboard, it will be removed from Clipboard after I close the application. How to disable this?

.NET 4.0

```
Syste.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(myText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetDataObject is non-persistent. Try to use

`System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text,myText);`

if you sure it is a text, you can use

`System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(myText);`

either.

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject` function [has a specific overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz(v=vs.110).aspx) to *copy* the contents into the clipboard instead of referencing it, exactly for this purpose.

So just use it as

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(myText, true);
```